# Logical right shift in C with ~0 value

Tags: c

I have a very simple code, in which logical shift works with ~0 value in strange way

As I know its related to the signed/unsigned data types

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printfbits(int x) {
    for (int i=7; i>=0;i--) {
        printf("%d", x>>i & 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    printfbits(~0>>1); 
}
```

I expect 0111111, not 1111111.
I also tried, no success

```
printfbits(((unsigned int)~0)>>1);
```

Comment: int type is 32 bits, not 8.

Comment: Right! I've tried char and it works now!

Comment: @AlexF C `int`s are not necessarily 32 bits! They can be any size of 16 bits and greater. Common sizes nowadays are 16, 32, and 64 bits.

Answer (score 7):

On most platforms, `int` is 32 bits or 64 bits long. Therefore, you are shifting more than 8 bits to the right, which leaves you with more than 8 bits enabled:

```
11...11111111 >> 1
```

becomes:

```
11...11111111 // if sign extension happens
01...11111111 // if not
```

As you see, regardless of whether sign extension happens or not, you will still see all `1`s since you only print the lower 8 bits.

Answer (score 4):

Right shift of negative signed values is **implementation defined**.  For gcc, a 1 is shifted in, otherwise a 0 is shifted in.

You were on the right track with the cast, but it doesn't help since the function still expects an `int`.  You need to change the function to take an `unsigned char` and you have to mask out all but the lowest byte before performing the shift in the function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printfbits(unsigned char x) {
    for (int i=7; i>=0;i--) {
        printf("%d", x>>i & 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    printfbits((~0u & 0xff)>>1);
}
```

Also, note the use of the `U` suffix on the constant 0.  That gives the constant a type of `unsigned int`.

Comment: While the C standard indeed says that the behavior of `>>` is implementation-defined when the first operand is negative, I challenge you to find me even a single modern C implementation that _doesn't_ define it as an [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) by default. The language in the standard is basically a relic of ancient compilers for ancient CPUs that used something other than [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed integers.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: It would be helpful if someone with some clout made a bona fide effort to recognize all the useful things that were pretty much standardized by the late 1990s, before compiler writers decided that Undefined Behavior meant "jump the rails, *even if the execution environment would define a useful behavior*".  I've beta-tested a compiler where signed right-shift was processed identically to unsigned; after my complaints (and perhaps those of other beta testers) the vendor recognized that even though the behavior was allowable and the processor could handle it faster...

Comment: ...than a sign-extending shift in some cases, sign-extending behavior was definitely preferable on two's-complement platforms.  What's funny is that the C99 Standard decided to change left shifts of negative numbers from being rigidly defined on most implementations to being Undefined Behavior in all cases on all implementations, even though C99's requirement for an unsigned type of 64 bits or longer made C99 impractical to implement on anything but the twos'-complement platforms where there would often only be only one sensible behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The negation in `~0` will happen with type `int`.
But even if you do `~(unsigned char)0`, it'll still happen with type int because of implicit promotions.
Consequently, you'll get extra more 1-bits on the left (int is usually 32 bits large (must be at least 16)).
You can strip them by casting the bitnegation result to `uint8_t`.

I'd also recommend doing bit ops on `unsigned`s (`0`u rather than `0`) as the semantics are better standardized for those.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void printfbits(int x) {
    for (int i=7; i>=0;i--) {
        printf("%d", x>>i & 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    printfbits( (uint8_t)~0u >>1 );  //prints 01111111
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is signed shift which is implementation defined. But on most 2 complement machines:

[image]

Comment: Regardless of sign extension, OP would still see all `1`s assuming `int` is longer than 8-bit.